# Nodejs display undefined on console even when function has return value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was just playing with node and I noticed even when I specify a return value for my function node still returns undefined.

[image: screenshot]

Whats wrong here? reading previous post related to my question, I am under the impression that if you specify a return type node shouldn't display undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't return `undefined`, it clearly returns `5`. The function **declaration** returns `undefined` (mainly because of (a) how `eval()` works and (b) [because functions with no return values technically return `undefined` per the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4)), but when you make a call to the function itself, e.g. `x()`, you get back a `5`.

You'll notice that variable declarations in the global scope, like `var test = 1`, also will immediately return an `undefined` in the console. This does not mean that `test` is now `undefined`.

Comment: what do you mean by functions with no return values? doesn't the function have a return value? or am I wrong

Comment: The function `x` has a return value, but Node parses what you see through the console with `eval` (or a similar method), so really the code "under the hood" looks like `eval("function x() { y = 5; return y; }")` -- note that there's nothing to return here. All you're doing is declaring a function.